# Ionic Modal Scope resets on each present

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

Well..I hit a bump.
I present a modal, change some variables inside its scope, and when I reopen it again the scope has been reset to the default.
Here is how I open it.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ModalController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginModal } from '../../modals/login/login.modal'
import { ExamplePage } from '../../pages/example/example'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  modal = null;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

  }

  openModal(){
    if(!this.modal)
      this.modal = this.modalCtrl.create(LoginModal, { userId: 8675309 });

    this.modal.present();
  }

}
```

And here is the modal component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ModalController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'login-modal',
    template: `
        <ion-content>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Title</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" (change)="onTitleChange()" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-content>
    `
})
export class LoginModal {
    title = 'Default.'

    onTitleChange(){
        console.log(this.title)
    }
}
```

Any idea why each time the modal is opened, the field is 'Default'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to retrieve variables from the modal on close

```
this.modal.onDidDismiss(data => console.log(data));
```

and send them when you open it during create.

```
this.modalCtrl.create(LoginModal, { userId: 8675309,title:savedTitle });
```

Check the ModalController [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/).
A modal is immediately destroyed on dismissing. So its data is not saved which means a new modal is created and presented which will have the default value.